# Magento - How do i read flatrate settings?

Tags: magento

How can i read flatrate and freeshipping settings in Magento?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example, this tells if flatrate is enabled:

```
Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('carriers/flatrate/active')
```

This retrieves it's price:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/flatrate/price')
```